# How do we map/fold over Option[String]?

Tags: scala

I have a parameter that is of type `Option[String]`. I know we can map or fold over it which would give a `String`. I want to use the `String` in another operation.

I am not able to do that.
Could you guys please help me with an example?

Comment: `myOptionString.map(myString => anotherOperation(myString))`

Comment: @Lasf What is anotherOperation here?

Comment: I think you'd do well to take at look at the numerous Scala tutorials available online. After that you'll be better prepared to ask questions here.

Comment: @niel `anotherOperation` is the operation you wanted to use the string for in your question.  If this is not what you mean can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Option[String]`, you have two choices:

1. Get the `String` out
2. Compute inside the `Option`

**To get the String out**, you can use pattern matching:

```
def printOption(parameter: Option[String]): Unit = 
  parameter match {
    case None => println("there was no string")
    case Some(theString) => println("the string was " + theString)
  }
```

Or you can use `getOrElse`:

```
def getTheStringOrSmile(parameter: Option[String]): String =
  parameter.getOrElse(":)")
```

**To compute inside the Option**, you can use higher-order functions such as `map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, `filter` and so on. These are called "higher-order functions" because they are functions that have parameters that are functions itself.

For example, let's look at `foreach` which takes a function from `String` (or whatever is in the `Option`) to `Unit`. If the option contains a value, `foreach` will call the function. If the option doesn't contain a value, nothing will happen. So we can write:

```
def printOptionIfPresent1(parameter: Option[String]): Unit =
  parameter.foreach(theString => println("the string was " + theString))
```

The syntax `theString => println("the string was " + theString)` constructs a function here. `theString` is the parameter of the function, and `println("the string was " + theString)` is the body of the function.

If you're struggling with the `theString => ...` syntax, maybe the following alternative implementation of `printOptionIfPresent1` helps you to see what's going on:

```
class Helper$123 extends Function[String, Unit] {
  def apply(theString: String): Unit =
    println("the string was + theString)
}

def printOptionIfPresent2(parameter: Option[String]): Unit =
  parameter.foreach(new Helper$123)
```

When the Scala compiler sees `printOptionIfPresent1` it more or less transforms it into something like `printOptionIfPresent1` and generates the correct `Helper$123` class for you.

The `foreach` method is good if you want something to happen (here: printing to the console) but don't want to return a value. If you want to return a value, use the `map` method instead. For example, to compute the length of a string inside an option, you can use:

```
def optionalLength1(parameter: Option[String]): Option[Int] =
  parameter.map(theString => theString.length)
```

This returns `None` if the parameter was `None`, too. If you want to just return an `Int` and use `0` for the case that the parameter is `None`, you can add `getOrElse` to get the `Int` out:

```
def optionalLength2(parameter: Option[String]): Int =
  parameter.map(theString => theString.length).getOrElse(0)
```

Hopefully that gives you a start, but make sure to explore `filter` and `flatMap`, too.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, that you can `map` and `fold` over an `Option` in scala. For the sake of simplicity let's pretend `Option` is a specialized `List` with either one or no entry.

To access the content we have many options. The easiest one would be retrieving it with `get`. But as you stated, you want to use `map` or `fold`. Therefore we need to understand those functions first.

Let's start with `fold`. Generally speaking there are two kinds of `fold`: `foldLeft` and `foldRight`. Where `foldLeft` will start with the head of the collection to perform a certain task, `foldRight` will do it in reverse order. Anyway both have two parameterlists. The first one contains the starting value and the second one the function to perform on each element. This function must take two parameters the accumulator, which will be passed on through the iterations and the current element. The result of the function must be suitable for the next iterations accumulator. The type of the accumulator is infered from the starting value. The result of the folding operation will always be of same type as the starting value.

```
// Adds all numbers in the list
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)((accumulator, element) => accumulator += element)
>res0: Int = 10
// Same as above method, but shortened with syntactic sugar
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(0)(_ + _)
>res1: Int = 10
// will also add all elements, but with an offset of 5
List(1,2,3,4).foldLeft(5)(_ + _)
>res2: Int = 15
```

Now let's move on to `map`. This function iterates over all elements and modifies each with the provided function. Te result will be the same collection type, typed with the type of the result of the function.

```
// multiplies each element by 2
List(1,2,3,4).map(element => element * 2)
>res0: List[Int] = List(2,4,6,8)
// the same as above, but shortened with syntactic sugar
List(1,2,3,4).map(_ * 2)
>res1: List[Int] = List(2,4,6,8)
```

If we apply this knowledge to `Option`, we can use it as follows:

```
// multiply contents by 2
List(5).map(_ * 2)
>res0: List[Int] = List(10)
Some(5).map(_ * 2)
>res1: Option[Int] = Some(10)

// multiply empty content by 2
val empty: Option[Int] = None // None cannot be typed
empty.map(_ * 2)
>res2: Option[Int] = None
List[Int]().map(_ * 2)
>res3: List[Int] = List()
```

As you can see, it is simple to access an element inside a `map` function. Plus you are protected from `NullPointerException`, because `map` only evaluates on non-empty collections.

Comment: It may be useful to mention that `fold` on Option is defined this way: `def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B)`. One can use it like better syntax replacing `MyOption.map(it => f(it)).getOrElse(default)` with `MyOption.fold(defaultValue)(a => f(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `String` value from `Option[String]`, use `getOrElse` and specify a default value in case the `Option` is `None`:

```
val str = strOption.getOrElse("default")
```

If you want to do some processing first, use `map`:

```
val str = strOption.map(_.drop(1)).getOrElse("default")
```

If you want to do some processing that returns a different type, use `fold`:

```
val strLen = strOption.fold(0)(_.length)
```

Note that in this case the default comes before the computation.

Answer (score -2):

you can do it like this.

```
val strOption :Option[String] = Some("test")

val str :String = strOption.getOrElse("")
print(str) // test
```

or you can do it like this.

```
// your logic inside the function

def otherOperation(inputStr:String):
    println(inputStr)

strOption.map(str :String => otherOpration(str))
```

this is how you will get str and you can use it anywhere you want. Where otherOperation is the function where you want to use that str.

Comment: here "str" is a String? But we have not initialized str with a String anywhere.. Could you explain me that?

Comment: if is the expression in scala and it returns value what ever we are writing in if and else (the last line of if and else) to match the type i have return the blank string. in other languages like java if is statement not the expression so it doesn't return anything

Comment: I was asking about the "map" part.

strOption.map(str=> otherOpration(str))..

How does str becomes a String here?

Comment: What do we have inside Option?? and please read about scala monads Option is one of them.

Comment: This is not the right way to use `Option`, use `getOrElse` rather than `get`.

Comment: @Tim is is one of the way of using option and if language is providing the functionality we can use it anyway i have updated it with getOrElse